# How to create an object during runtime with user input reference type, object name and parameters in Java

Tags: java, oop, object

I want to be able to dynamically create an employee object from user input. I have two different classes made already one being a manager and one being an associate. I should be able to input what type of employee I want to create and the name and age of the employee. 
How can I do this?

```
while (true){

System.out.print("Input the type of employee: "); 

String type = Input.next();

//Can only be "manager" or "associate"


System.out.print("Input the name of the employee: ");

String name = Input.next();

System.out.print("Input the age of the employee: ");

int age = Input.nextInt();


/*The name of the object should also be the name of the employee
*Depending on what "Type" is given from the user determines what type of object the new object is going to be 
*/

type name = new type(name,age)

//type is not the reference type but a variable holding the reference *type
*/
}
```

I expect that I should be able to create as many objects as I want of either reference type: manager or associate. With different names and ages

Comment: OK, and what's the actual question you have? You can, btw, or you should be able to, if you understand how to: 1. instantiate objects 2. maybe use setters 3. use loops

Comment: 1- Make sure you've collected all the parameters you need to create the object 
2 - Construct it 
3 - Store it on a Linked List or any other structure that is designed for easy dynamic additions.

Comment: @Stultuske the actual question is how can I do this, what syntax would make this concept of creating that object during runtime with user input work. Also, I don't yet understand what instantiate objects are or setters and I wouldn't know how to use loops to make this work but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @AskedSuperior if you don't know what instantiating objects is, you can't possibly create and use an object, because in order to do so, you need to instantiate an object. "what syntax", you mean you don't know the basics, but you want us to provide you with ready-made code? If you don't know where loops fit into your description, you either don't know what loops are, or it is the simple logic of your requirement, not the code, you are having trouble with

Comment: @stultuske well yea I don't know that much I'm still learning the language and programming in general, that was kind of the point of me asking the question because I don't know what to do. However, if you're suggesting that in order to do the task that I'm asking, I need to learn how to instantiate objects then I will learnit.

Comment: @AskedSuperior you already are instantiating objects, you obviously haven't figured that out yet. Stop trying to cut corners. buy a decent textbook and start at chapter 1. study it, without skipping chapters because they "seem easy". We can try to help you, but you also have to be able to understand the explanation you are given, or any explanation is worthless.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a String variable as a class name. Instead of

```java
type name = new type(name,age)
```

try

```java
if ("manager".equals(type)) {
    Manager mgr = new Manager(name, age);
} else {
    Associate asc = new Associate(name, age);
}
```

This assumes you have the classes `Manager` and `Asssociate` defined somewhere and they each have a constructor that takes a `String` and an `int`.

Comment: Yes that would somewhat work but part of the problem is that I need to make separate objects with different names, not only "mgr" or "asc" as object names. The object name would also have to be able to vary.